# list constructors conflict in Coq

Tags: coq

I have the following definitions in Coq:

```
Inductive list_variable : Type :=
| nil
| cons (s : string) (l : list_variable).

Fixpoint getElement (l : list_variable) (s : Variabile) (v : Address) {struct l} : Address :=
match l with
| nil => v
| str :: nil => (updateValues v ((updateState (updateState s "memPointer" (s("memPointer")+1)) str (s("memPointer"))) "memPointer") undef)
| str :: l => getElement l s v
end.
```

For some reason, the bottom and second line return `Found a constructor of inductive type list while a constructor of list_variable is expected.`

For reference, the long return on `str::nil` works fine in another place. It's for a memory-like simulation.

Any ideas as to why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation `::` desugars to `List.cons`, whereas you want the constructor `MyModule.cons`. If you want to use `::`, you must define a new notation for it:

```
Inductive list_variable : Type :=
| nil
| cons : ...
.

(* Redefine "::" for new list type *)
Infix "::" := cons.
```

If you intend to use the same notation for both `list` and `list_variable`, it will be necessary to manage notation scopes. Refer to [the Coq manual, the section on notations](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html).

Comment: Hi, I'm not planning on using lists other than that, so hopefully this should help. Thanks!

Comment: @RaduDeleanu if this answer satisfies you then please consider *accepting* it.